# Throw my own Exception in Angular 2, Angular wraps it with viewWrappedDebugError

Tags: angular

I am building a decent sized Angular 2 application and I have created my own Exception to roll my own error handling mechanisms.  But it seems Angular is trying to wrap my error in some `viewWrappedDebugError`

My Exception:

**ClientRuntimeException.ts**

```
export class ClientRuntimeException {
  id: string;
  timestamp: Date;
  origin: ErrorOrigin;
  errorDisplayMethod: ErrorDisplayMethod;
  message: string;
  stack: string;

  constructor(shortMessage: string, displayMethod?: ErrorDisplayMethod) {
    this.id = Guid.newGuid();
    this.timestamp = new Date(Date.now());
    this.origin = ErrorOrigin.CLIENT;
    this.message = shortMessage;
    this.stack = new Error().stack;
    this.errorDisplayMethod = displayMethod || ErrorDisplayMethod.DEFAULT;
  }
```

I've implemented an ExceptionHandler to catch my own (and other) exceptions:

**exception-handling.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ExceptionHandlingService extends ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I've injected the ErrorHandling service correctly in my core.module.ts:

```
...
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ExceptionHandlingService },
...
```

The problem is, Angular seems to be trying to wrap my exception in something else before it reaches the Handler.

To test, I'm throwing my own ClientRuntimeException in the ngOnInit method of some component:

**some-component.ts**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        throw new ClientRuntimeException("my message");
    }
}
```

But immediately inside my ErrorHandler, I'm getting someone else's exception:

```
ERROR: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [object Object]
Error: [object Object]
    at viewWrappedDebugError (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:8862:15) [angular]
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:13283:15) [angular]
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:12812:12) [angular]
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:10382:63) [angular]
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23997:42) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23175:16) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23156:26) [angular]
    at http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:58 [angular]
    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:29) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23157:26) [angular]
    at http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:58 [angular]
    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:29) [angular]: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [object Object]
Error: [object Object]
    at viewWrappedDebugError (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:8862:15) [angular]
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:13283:15) [angular]
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:12812:12) [angular]
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:10382:63) [angular]
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23997:42) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23175:16) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23156:26) [angular]
    at http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:58 [angular]
    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:29) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23157:26) [angular]
    at http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:58 [angular]
    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:23092:29) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/polyfills.bundle.js:745:31) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/polyfills.bundle.js:716:17) [angular]
    at http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/polyfills.bundle.js:793:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/vendor.bundle.js:4348:37) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.1291.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/polyfills.bundle.js:430:36) [angular]
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.1291.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/polyfills.bundle.js:198:47) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/polyfills.bundle.js:626:35) [<root>]
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/cred-services/ng-dist/polyfills.bundle.js:497:25) [<root>]
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: @Alessandro ... Yes! I did a couple months back, I just added my answer below.  You need to extend Error.  Please upvote if it works for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue.  Your ClientRuntimeException needs to extend the ES6 `Error`.  There seems to be some Angular code that checks to see if the thrown object extends Error and if it doesn't it tries to wrap it in something of it's own.

```
export class ClientRuntimeException extends Error {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  timestamp: Date;
  origin: ErrorOrigin;
  errorDisplayMethod: ErrorDisplayMethod;
  message: string;
  stack: string;

  constructor(shortMessage: string, displayMethod?: ErrorDisplayMethod) {
    super(shortMessage);
    this.id = Guid.newGuid();
    this.name = 'Error@' + window.location.href;
    this.timestamp = new Date(Date.now());
    this.origin = ErrorOrigin.CLIENT;
    this.message = shortMessage;
    this.errorDisplayMethod = displayMethod || ErrorDisplayMethod.DEFAULT;
  }
}
```